# Obtener solo el año de un input

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo un problema al obtener solo el año en un input a través de una consulta en JavaScript. Intento hacer que al seleccionar una fecha de un `input` tipo `date`, en otro input solo me dé el año, ya conseguí que me pase la fecha en el otro `input`, pero me pasa toda la fecha y busco que solo se pueda pasar el año.

Adjunto el código:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#pridosis").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("#calculofecha").val(value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" name="pridosis" id="pridosis" value="" /><br>
<input type="text" name="text2" id="calculofecha" value="<?php echo date_format('Y') ?>" disabled/>
```

Comment: Ya intentaste value.getFullYear() ?

Comment: HTML no tiene un componente nativo de año, lo habitual es usar un input number y colocar el rango en el min-value y el max-value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ahora mismo sólo estás copiando el valor de un campo en el otro. Si sólo quieres el año, transforma el valor del primer campo en una fecha (usando la clase [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date)) y obtén el valor del año con el método [`getFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/getFullYear).

Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#pridosis").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("#calculofecha").val(new Date(value).getFullYear());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" name="pridosis" id="pridosis" value="" /><br>
<input type="text" name="text2" id="calculofecha" value="<?php echo date_format('Y') ?>" disabled/>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Alvaro funciona a la perfección.